# Question about restriction of holomorphic vector bundle.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

There is a statement as follows:

For $E\to M$ a holomorphic vector bundle and $V\subset M$ a subvariety, the kernel of the restriction map $\mathcal{O}_M(E)\to \mathcal{O}_V(E)$ is the sheaf of sections of a vector bundle if and only if $V$ is of codimension 1 in $M$.

I think the kernel is the sections that vanish on $V$. How does the dimension of $V$ come into the picture? Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I_V$ be the ideal sheaf of $V$, there is an exact sequence

$$0\to I_V\to \mathcal{O}_M\to \mathcal{O}_V\to 0.$$

It is an exercise to show that the ideal sheaf $I_V$ is locally free if and only if $V$ is of codimension one.
Now tensor the sequence with the vector bundle $E$, then you will get the result.

Comment: Is it because if the ideal sheaf is locally free, the defining function of $Y$ must be extended to a global one, thus $Y$ is of codimension one?

Comment: @YuyiZhang You can check the stalk at a smooth point $x$: If $(I_V)_x\cong (\mathcal{O}_M)_x$ , then $V$ is defined by one equation around $x$. I don't think this is related to defining function being global.